# universal image loader load image from server with Json

Tags: universal-image-loader

I downloading the ( universal image loader sample project ) from github 
and importing to the eclipse and pushing the F5 button to executing the application and every thing is 
good and I seeing good result in listView - GridView - gallery and more ..

now I have a question 
how I can load the image from my server (my Json)
Where I need to change my codes?
this is my Constants.java (in sample project of universal )

```
package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.sample;
```

/**
 * @author Sergey Tarasevich (nostra13[at]gmail[dot]com)
 */
public final class Constants {

```
public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[]{
                                    // Heavy images
                                    "http://www.androidinfo.ir/ssapp/logo/3.jpg",
                                    "www.androidinfo.ir/ssapp/serviceeee.php?action=read",

                                    };


private Constants() {}


public static class Config {

    public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
}


public static class Extra {

    public static final String FRAGMENT_INDEX = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.FRAGMENT_INDEX";
    public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
}
```

}